# multibind image source in xaml & wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

In my project, i have a folder called Images, where all the images iam using in my application are saved in subfolders.All the images are set to "Resource" in the buildprocess.

```
myproject
  |__Images
      |__AppImages
          |__StarOn.png
          |__StarOff.png
```

Now, if i do set my image manually like this:

```
<Image Source="Images\AppImages\StarOn.png" width="32" height="32"/>
```

the image is correctly shown in the imagebox.

i would like to set the image using a converter and a binding like this:

```
<Image>
<Image.Source>
  <Binding Path="Number" converter="{StaticResource GetImagePathConverter}"/>
</Image.Source>
</Image>
```

where the number is an integer

and my converter is:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int questionNr=int.parse(value.ToString());

            if (questionNr>100)
            {
                return "Images\\AppImages\\StarOn.png";
            }

            return "Images\\AppImages\\starOff.png";
    }
```

but this is not changing the image ?..

what iam doing wrong ?
how can i set the image source correctly from the converter ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your way of using converter is incorrect. You need to create an instance of your converter use it in your binding through `StaticResource`. `local:` is the local namespace which you need to declare in your xaml -

```
<Image>
  <Image.Resources>
    <local:GetImagePathConverter x:Key="GetImagePathConverter"/>
  </Image.Resources>
  <Image.Source>
    <Binding Path="Number" Converter="{StaticResource GetImagePathConverter}"/>
  </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Also, `Source` property is not of type string but instead `ImageSource` so you need something in your converter -

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
   int questionNr=int.parse(value.ToString());

   if (questionNr>100)
   {
      return new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images\\AppImages\\StarOn.png", UriKind.Relative));
   }
   return new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images\\AppImages\\StarOff.png", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: hi ...thank you for your answer..iam using it correctly in my code..i just forgot to write it here ...thanks again i will edit my question

Comment: the return in your answer is not of type ImageSource ..right ?

Comment: BitmapImage implements class BitmapSource which eventually derives from ImageSource. Hence the return type is of `ImageSource`.

Comment: ok, i tried it, iam getting an exception:Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

Comment: Set mode to be `Relative` for an URI. Refer to this link for the reason - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734120/cannot-set-image-source-in-code-behind

Comment: JA ..exactly thanks

new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images\AppImages\starOn.png",UriKind.Relative));

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502171/multibinding-not-working-on-textbox-text/10502735#10502735).

Basically, you have to take care of the type of object that you return in your converter, you cannot return `string` to a property of `ImageSource` type.

I'm not on my dev machine, but the code is something like this:

```
return new BitmapImage(new Uri(the/path/to/image.png)).Source; //or '*.ImageSource', can't remember
```